# Why only L is used behind a number in R programming to make it a integer? Why not any other Alphabet?

Tags: r, variables, integer, double

By default, it takes a number as double in R. And we have to add L to change it to an integer. But why  L? We could have used A,B, C, etc or any other Alphabet?

Comment: L stands for "Long Integer" - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer_%28computer_science%29#Long_integer

Comment: Because this is how "they" determined (perhaps arbitrarily, informed by other languages and standards) it would be when they first developed S and then R. "They" are the original developers. Why does python use `def` to define a function, why not `define`? Why does lisp use parens, why not braces or brackets? Questions that might be entertaining over a beverage or over lunch, but ... not really a good fit for StackOverflow.